# javascript function set upload file field to deafult

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload, field, default

I have a simple upload form and when I click in "Add more files", it sets to default all the previous fields.

**Example:** click in "Add more files", then add a file, and finally click again in "Add more files". It will remove all the previous files ... why ? I don't wanna remove any file.

```
function create(){
   var s= document.getElementById("number_of_forms").innerHTML;
   s+= '<input input type="file"name="file" id="file"><br>';
   document.getElementById("number_of_forms").innerHTML=s;i++;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/aaSR7/4/

Comment: `id="file"`? Hardcoded? Into a function you reuse? Don't do that. IDs must be unique.

Comment: I know, that's not the point, this is just an example.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't simply adding a field to the `number_of_forms` element.

You are getting the HTML for that element, adding a new input to that HTML, then generating new DOM elements from that HTML and inserting them back into the element (replacing all the existing ones).

Don't use `innerHTML`. Use `createElement`, `appendChild` and friends.

Comment: i've just got the same answer so added a fiddle to your answer

Comment: @karthik the fiddle is not complete, it lacks a name for the input and newline between them for one.

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle to your answer please ?

Comment: @ShadowWizard oh yeah. I just got implemented what is required

Comment: add the jsfiddle please